# Prove that, if $x_n \geq 0$, $a > 0$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\lim_{x\to\infty} x_n = a$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{x_n} = \sqrt{a}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> Prove that, if $x_n \geq 0$, $a > 0$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$,
>   $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = a$ then
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{x_n} = \sqrt{a}$$

It looks kind of obvious but I'm having trying to prove it.

My attempt:

Let assume the opposite That is, if $x_n \geq 0$, $a > 0$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = a$ then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{x_n} = b \neq \sqrt{a}$$

Then it follows that $b^2 \neq a$. But, by applying one of the properties of arithmetic with limits we have that

$$a = \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}  \sqrt{x_n}\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{x_n} = b \cdot b = b^2 $$

which contradicts our first assumption. Then it follows that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{x_n} = b \neq \sqrt{a}$$

Is this okay? I'm not quite convinced.

Comment: Presumably you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{x_n}$.

Comment: @carmichael561 Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = a > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$\left| x_n - a\right| < \sqrt{a}\varepsilon$$ for each $n > N$. Hence for $n > N$ $$\left| \sqrt{x_n} - \sqrt{a}\right| = \frac{1}{\left| \sqrt{x_n} + \sqrt{a}\right|}\left| x_n - a\right| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\sqrt{a}\varepsilon = \varepsilon$$ Since $\varepsilon$ was choosen arbitrarily, we conclude $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{x_n} = \sqrt{a}$$

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is not correct because you are *assuming*  that
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{x_n} = b$ exists.

But you can prove it using that $t\to t^2$ is *strictly increasing*
on $(0, \infty)$. If $0 < \varepsilon < \sqrt a$ then
$$
  0 < \sqrt a - \varepsilon < \sqrt a < \sqrt a + \varepsilon \\
\Longrightarrow
  0 < (\sqrt a - \varepsilon)^2 < a < (\sqrt a + \varepsilon)^2 \, .
$$
From $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = a$ it follows that there is a $N \in \Bbb N$
such that
$$
  0 < (\sqrt a - \varepsilon)^2 < x_n < (\sqrt a + \varepsilon)^2 
\quad \text{ for } n \ge N 
$$
which implies that
$$
  0 < \sqrt a - \varepsilon < \sqrt{x_n} < \sqrt a + \varepsilon
\quad \text{ for } n \ge N  \, .
$$

So this is a special case of the fact that the inverse
function of a strictly increasing function on an interval
is continuous, see for example
[Continuity of an inverse function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672174/continuity-of-an-inverse-function).

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient notice that square root is  a continuous function on $[0,+\infty) $.

Comment: That's indeed an equivalent way of interpreting the problem. However, I don't think it helps as you can consider this question as a proof that $\sqrt{x}$ is continuous on $[0,+\infty )$.