# Differentiable bijection $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with nonzero derivative whose inverse is not differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, inverse-function, inverse-function-theorem

I had an exam today, and I was asked about the inverse function theorem, and the exact conditions and statement (as stated in Mathematical Analysis by VA Zorich):
Let $X, Y \subset \mathbb{R}$ be open sets and let the functions $f: X \to Y$ and $f^{-1}: Y \to X$ be mutually inverse and continuous at points $x_{0} \in X$ and $y_{0}=f(x_{0})$, respectively. If $f$ is differentiable at $x_{0}$ and $f'(x_{0}) \neq 0$, then $f^{-1}$ is also differentiable at $y_{0}$  and its derivative is $$(f^{-1})'(y_{0})=(f'(x_{0}))^{-1}=\frac{1}{f'(x_{0})}.$$

Then I was asked to come up with an example which would show that the condition that $f^{-1}$ be continuous at $y_{0}$ is not redundant, i.e. that there exists a differentiable bijection $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, but whose inverse $f^{-1}$ is non-differentiable at some point $y_{0} \in \mathbb{R}$ (my professor stated that both the domain and range are $\mathbb{R}$, but I'd be open to any example whose domain/range are **open** subsets of $\mathbb{R}$). I couldn't come up with an answer on the spot, so I was left with a homework assignment, which I'm shamelessly asking for help with here.

Here are some examples that almost, but don't quite fit the bill:

1. $f(x)=x^3, f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, whose inverse $f^{-1}(y)=\sqrt[3]y$ is not differentiable at $0$, but the problem is that $f'(0)=0$. If $f'(x) \neq 0$ were removed as a conditions, many counterexamples could be easily found, because any bijection $f$ whose derivative is zero at $x$ implies that $f^{-1}$ is not differentiable at $f(x)$.
2. An example which is possibly closer to what I'm looking for is the one found in the answer of [Functions which are Continuous, but not Bicontinuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68800/functions-which-are-continuous-but-not-bicontinuous), which fits the bill completely except for the domain/range, because $f^{-1}$ is not continuous at 1, let alone differentiable, but its domain is not an open or connected set, so it wouldn't be easy to extend its domain to $\mathbb{R}$ and still keep all of its properties.

I'm aware that the inverse $f^{-1}$ of a continuous bijection $f$ defined on an interval ($\mathbb{R}$ in this case) is also continuous, so the "pathological inverse" that I'm looking for is continuous (unlike example 2), but not differentiable (i.e. "spiky") at a point, even though $f$ isn't "spiky" anywhere.

Comment: What are $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: The book does not specify, but I assume from context that they're open sets in $\mathbb{R}$. I'll edit it accordingly.

Comment: If it helps, your counterexample cannot be continuously differentiable. You can restate the theorem with a $C^1$-function and remove the condition that $f^{-1}$ be continuous at $y_0$. In particular, if $f$ is $C^1$ and $f'$ is nowhere zero, then $f$ is strictly monotone. Every strictly monotone continuous function has a continuous inverse.

Comment: I see, so I'm looking for something with a weird derivative (but which is also monotone), like $x^2 \sin{\frac{1}{x}}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $0$ for $x=0$. Maybe $x+x^2 \sin{\frac{1}{x}}$?

Comment: That is the standard example, though your suggestion is not differentiable at $0$ (assuming $f(0) = 0$).

Comment: Oh, that's true, too bad. I had just started getting my hopes up after looking at the graph of the derivative on wolframalpha. Back to the drawing board, then.

Comment: Could you explain why $x+x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}$ isn't differentiable at $0$, though? I'm getting $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h+h^2\sin\frac{1}{h}}{h} = 1$.

Comment: It certainly is differentiable at $0.$ You might want to have $2x$ instead of $x$ however.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. I was making the same mistake in my head that I had suggested we use; namely, that the derivative is not continuous. [The sum of differentiable functions is certainly differentiable]

Comment: So by analyzing $x \geq \frac{1}{\pi}$ and $x < \frac{1}{\pi}$, I was able to show that $f(x)=2x+x^2\sin{\frac{1}{x}}$ is a differentiable bijection with $f' > 0$. Is there a good way to determine if $f^{-1}$ is differentiable?

Comment: I think I hit a dead end with this, though: since $f$ is differentiable and continuous on an open set, by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain, its inverse is also continuous, so the conditions of the inverse function theorem are satisfied.

Comment: The inverse function theorem doesn't require continuous differentiability, see e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75049/does-the-inverse-function-theorem-hold-for-everywhere-differentiable-maps

Comment: @ColinMcQuillan Indeed. However, if you have continuous differentiability, then you can exclude the part about $f^{-1}$ being continuous at $f(x_0)$ and that part is redundant. Hence to show that this hypothesis is necessary, the counter-example cannot be continuously differentiable.

Comment: @MoisheCohen So if I were to weaken a condition, i.e. only ask for the bijection $f$ to be differentiable at a certain point $x_{0}$, without talking about its differentiability on the rest of the domain, I could come up with an example where $f^{-1}$ is not differentiable at $f(x_{0})=y_{0}$? The closest example I found was example no. 2 in the question, but since the domain is $[0, 1] \cup (2, 3]$, we can only talk about the left derivative of $f$ at $1$. Is there a better example, where $f$ is both left- and right-differentiable at a point, and the inverse still isn't differentiable?

Comment: @MoisheCohen Would you care to add an answer with such an example, or would you prefer if I ask a new question? Also I forgot to add to the "new conditions" $f'(x_{0}) \neq 0$.

Comment: @MatijaSreckovic Yes, in my example the domain is an open interval.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On whether "there exists a differentiable bijection $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, but whose inverse $f^{-1}$ is non-differentiable at some point $y_{0} \in \mathbb{R}$":  I don't think this is possible.

Proof: Recall that every continuous bijection on $\mathbb R$ has a continuous inverse. So certainly this holds for $f.$ Consider the difference quotient

$$\tag 1 \frac{f^{-1}(y) - f^{-1}(y_0)}{y-y_0}  = \frac{f^{-1}(y) - f^{-1}(y_0)}{f(f^{-1}(y))- f(f^{-1}(y_0))}.$$

As $y\to y_0,$ $f^{-1}(y) \to f^{-1}(y_0).$ Thus $(1)$ converges to the familiar $\dfrac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(y_0))}$ and we're done.

**Added later:** With reference to the comments below, I found the following example: On $(-1,2)$ define $f(x) = x$ on $(-1,0].$ On $(0,1)$ we do something more complicated while keeping $f(x)$ trapped between $g(x) = x$ and $h(x) =x+x^2.$ In so doing we are guaranteed $f'(0)=1.$

On the interval $I_n =(1/(n+1),1/n)$ define $f$ to equal the line through $(1/(n+1), h(1/(n+1))$  and $(1/n,g(1/n)).$ Then $f(I_n) = (h(1/(n+1),g(1/n)).$ Verify that $f$ is between $g$ and $h$ on each $I_n.$ Also notice that the intervals $f(I_n)$ have gaps betweem them. For example $f(I_1) = (3/4,1),$ $f(I_2) = (4/9,1/2).$

So we've defined $f$ on $(-1,1).$ Now there is a bijection from $[1,2)$ onto all the above-mentioned gaps, i. e., onto $(0,1)\setminus \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}f(I_n).$ Define $f$ to be this bijection on $[1,2).$

Then $f$ maps $(-1,2)$ bijectively onto $(-1,1),$ $f(0)=0,$ $f'(0) = 1,$ but $f^{-1}$ fails to be continuous at $0$ (because there are sequences $\to 0^+$ that $f^{-1}$ sends to $[1,2)$).

Comment: I think, there might be an issue with your interpretation of the problem. The way I read the question, continuity of $f$ is assumed only at one point,  $x_0$. Your answer assumes continuity on an open interval. With my interpretation, there are indeed examples that he was asked to construct.

Comment: @MoisheCohen  I was addressing the problem in the paragraph that begins "Then I was asked to come up with an example ..."

Comment: Oh, I see, I did not read the question closely.

Comment: @MoisheCohen I'm glad you brought it up, because there are a number of situations mentioned in the OP. I'll edit to make this clearer.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Even though I got the answer to the question I asked here, I'm very interested in any example that sheds light on the necessity of the "continuous at $y_{0}$" condition. I left a reply for you in the OP comments section, but I see you deleted your comment from there, so I'll address you here too: could you share such an example? Either in this thread or in a new one if you think it's better.

Comment: @MatijaSreckovic I will, a bit later. Your professor might have meant my interpretation of the question, since it is closer to the theorem.

Comment: @MoisheCohen You and Matija got me thinking about this other problem. I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: @zhw.: Yes, this is similar to the example I had in mind, so I do not have to write my example.

Answer (score 4):

After some thoughts and discussions, I've come to the unfortunate realization that such a function ($f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable bijection, $f'>0$ WLOG (which is equivalent to $f' \neq 0$ because of Darboux's mean value theorem), $f^{-1}$ not everywhere-differentiable),  does not exist, for a rather trivial reason.

If $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ were a differentiable bijection, it would be a continuous bijection, and therefore by the invariance of domain theorem, $f^{-1}$ is also continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$, so all the conditions of the inverse funciton theorem are met, therefore $f^{-1}$ is differentiable everywhere.

**PS:** I'm not touting my horn by answering my own question, and zhw's answer is simpler than mine and correct, so I've accepted it. I just happened to write it out at the same time as them.

Comment: The invariance of domain theorem is very easy on $\mathbb R,$ and very difficult on $\mathbb R^n,n>1.$

Comment: Does it reduce to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672174/continuity-of-an-inverse-function for $n=1$?

Comment: Probably. It is a standard topology/real analysis result.

Comment: If $U,V$ are open in $\mathbb R$ and $f:U\to V$ is a continuous bijection then for $x\in U$ let $x\in (a,b$) where $[a,b]\subset  U.$ Then $f([a,b])$ is connected & compact (because $[a,b]$ is). So $f([a,b])=[c,d]$ with $c<d.$.... And $f(x)\not \in \{c,d\}$ (else by the MVT $f$ is not $1$-to-$1.)$... A continuous bijection from a  compact $T_2$ space to another is a homeomorphism. So $f|_{[a,b]}$ is a homeomorphism  .... So $f^{-1}|_{(c,d)}$ is continuous, with $f(x)\in (c,d)\subset V.$ Therefore $f^{-1}$ is locally continuous at every $f(x)\in V$ and therefore  $f^{-1}$ is continuous.